# Automate ssh serial-over-LAN connection to SuperMicro IPMI via Putty

Tags: ssh, putty, ipmi, supermicro

I recently found instructions on how to take advantage of the SuperMicro's serial-over-LAN remote console via SSH.  The challenge is after the SSH login a few commands must be executed to start the remote console.  As I cannot make any changes in the BMC or create a server-side script - I need to execute the commands manually.

The commands required, after login, are:

```
cd system1/sol1
start
```

So...is there a way this can be automated via Putty or Plink?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to enter the following in the PuTTY session properties, Configuration > SSH > Remote Command:

```
cd system/sol1 && start && /bin/bash
```

(or substitute your favorite shell or command at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a local file containing the commands and using the `-m` option when initiating the connection with plink?

> -m : read a remote command or script from a file
>
> ```
>    The `-m' option performs a similar function to the `Remote command'
>    box in the SSH panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see section
>    4.18.1). However, the `-m' option expects to be given a local file
>    name, and it will read a command from that file.
>
>    With some servers (particularly Unix systems), you can even put
>    multiple lines in this file and execute more than one command in
>    sequence, or a whole shell script; but this is arguably an abuse,
>    and cannot be expected to work on all servers. In particular, it is
>    known _not_ to work with certain `embedded' servers, such as Cisco
>    routers.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the current commands to run after you managed to connect to BMC using ssh are:

./usr/local/bin/solssh